# Simple stringLiteral matching fails when using JavaTokenParsers in Scala

Tags: regex, parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I've just started working on an external DSL, however I've run into an issue. I've written a very simple test, I use Scala 2.9.0-1 and scalatest 1.6.1:

```scala
class DSLTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  object DSL extends JavaTokenParsers {

    def test = stringLiteral

    def apply(s: String): Either[String, String] = parseAll(test, s) match {
      case Success(tree, _) => Right(tree.toString)
      case NoSuccess(msg, _) => Left("Bad syntax: " + msg)
    }

  }

  "DSL" should "parse ABC" in {
    val input = "ABC"
    DSL(input) match {
      case Right(r) =>
        r should be === """(ABC)""""
      case Left(msg) =>
        fail(msg)
    }
  }

}
```

If I run it, it fails during parsing and returns:

```
Bad syntax: string matching regex `"([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\/bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*"' expected but `A' found
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? I basically followed Dean Wampler's book (http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `stringLiteral` is something like this:

```
"I am a string literal because I'm between double quotes"
```

If you declare input like below, it should work:

```
val input = "\"ABC\""
```

Then again, there's an error in the right case:

```
    r should be === """(ABC)""""
```

should have been written

```
    r should be === """"(ABC)""""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now when you told me it was obvious.